# CSS Transition get laggy with many DOM Elements

Tags: css, css-transitions

While programming my web application, which contains a table, which can get pretty big, i noticed that my CSS Transitions get pretty laggy after a while.
After testing that with JSFiddle, i noticed that this also does happen with just a basic example. http://jsfiddle.net/tLjmkdto/1/

HTML

```
<body>
<button onclick="animateme()">Animate</button>
<button onclick="spamme()">Spam</button>
    <div class="animate"></div>

    <div class="spam"></div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
.animate {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: width 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.closed.closed {
    width: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
function animateme() {
    var anim = document.querySelector(".animate"); 
    if(anim.className == "animate closed") {
        anim.className = "animate";           
    } else {     
        anim.className = "animate closed";
    }
}


function spamme() {
    var spam = document.querySelector(".animate");
    for (i = 0; i < 30000; i++) { 
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var node = document.createTextNode(i);
            div.appendChild(node);
        spam.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Smooth with no Elements
Laggy with many Elements

So i want to know if there is a way to get this animation smooth. I'm using Dart and Polymer if that helps.

Comment: Why do you need 30,000 nodes?

Comment: i didnt animate 30k Nodes. I only animated the bordered Div. But the animation is laggy because there are 30k divs. 
And as i do have an pretty big table in my web app, I have that laggy effect on my page.

Answer (score 0):

you know that animation is shrinking all the divs in the container right? that 's a pretty expensive operation. you might be able to work around this by actually having the 30,000 divs in a container that *doesnt* animate, but has a "clip view" superimposed that does animate to show/hide what is beneath it. This way the size of the 30k divs doesnt change, but you should get the same visual effect. Not 100% certain that this will result in a perfectly smooth animation, but this was too long for a comment :)

Comment: The 30k Divs are in a seperate container, so they do not get animated.

Comment: @Azael your fiddle begs to differ. it doesnt matter if they are in a "separate" container if resizing the parent container causes the 30k divs to resize too.

Comment: yeah in my web app they are in a seperate container, but not inside the same parent. But still the animation is pretty slowly

Comment: @Azael as i said separate container means nothing if the animation results in resizing those divs. The strategy in my post is the only way i can think of that would prevent those from resizing when you hide them. can you make a fiddle that demonstrates the hierarchy you have better?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tLjmkdto/2/ Thats pretty close to my web app. Above is a collapseable Panel and below is a huge table. I know I use extremly many DOM Elements in this case, but since my web app has more complex Elements (Polymer Elements) i think this is pretty realistic.